# My laptop internal michrophone is not detected on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10, microphone

My internal Mic is not detected in Ubuntu 19.10. My system config and model is as follows:

No LSB modules are available:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description   : Ubuntu 19.10
Release       : 19.10
Codename      : eoan
```

[image: image1]

[[image: image 2]]

And this is my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file:

```
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

Comment: You have dmic_detect=0. That may be the reason. I have a similar problem. I have to add this option for my sound card to be recognized properly. But my microphone is not detected.